# Elastic 2.4 - Get substring of text field

Tags: elasticsearch, substring

I'm using Elastic 2.4 .
My JSON contains a "MessageBody" attribute that may hold 3M characters.
When querying events from Elastic, I'd like to get the entire JSON, but only a limited length of the "MessageBody" attribute, e.g.: only the first 100K chars.
Is it possible in Elastic 2.4 ?
I've added this section to my query:

```
"script_fields": {
    "short_body": {
        "script": {
            "inline": "_source.MessageBody.substring(0, 100000)"
        }
    }
}
```

This section doesn't impact the query. I still get the JSON as usual, with the full long MessageBody attribute.

I saw that "script_fields" is supported in 2.4 .
Is substring() also supported ? Did I write the query correctly ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please review and edit your question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: how are you getting the data, what data do you get and what happens with substring?

Comment: Those who down vote should explain why, and cancel if problem fixed.